# PHP AppEngine Create and add rows to spreadsheet

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Using AppEngine and PHP, I'd like to :

1. Create a new spreadsheet in a specified folder, name it.
2. Add headers to that spreadsheet.
3. Add rows to that spreadsheet.

It seems that this is incredibly difficult with the new updates to the PHP Client API.

I've achieved Step 1 using the official [PHP APIClient](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) with an **OAuth 2.0 client ID** and **Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE**,  scope however it doesn't seem to be possible to use the same client to add headers/rows to that spreadsheet.

Is this correct? Am I supposed to create a new **Service account** and use that to open the spreadsheet I've just created and add headers and rows using that?

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client ? Yes, you do have to use a different API for creating a spreadsheet than for then manipulating it, but both APIs are typical Google REST APIs, authorized via a valid OAuth access token -- why would you need a service account for one but not for the other?

Comment: Thanks Alex, that is exactly my question :) I have tried the asimlqt client but I have to use the official client to create the spreadsheet, then connect again using the asimlqt client, retrieve a list of spreadsheets and do a search for the newly created spreadsheet.

Comment: In addition, with this approach in order to write to the spreadsheet I have to explicitly, manually, share with the service account email 1@APPID.iam.gserviceaccount.com. This means my use case doesn't work.